# Why am I getting error while installing npm package?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install `mongodb` package using `npm intall mongodb` command. Unfortunately I am not able to install package and it ends up with following error:

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...st":{"shasum":"001f7b'`

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Can you share what your `package.json` looks like